# Javascript Date : One day off on tablet

Tags: javascript, date

I'm working with date in Javascript.

The goal is to show event on a certain date.

It's working perfectly on my PC.

It's working perfectly on my Google Pixel Phone.

BUT, it's not working on an iPad Mini or Samsung Galaxy Tab A.

The event just show one day before and one hour after.

```
shipments.forEach(shipment =>{
    var date = new Date(shipment.Date);

    if((date.getTime() != day.getTime())){
      shipments = shipments.filter(x => x.Id != shipment.Id);
    }
})
```

The timezone seems to be set OK on the two tablets.

I've tried multiple things, I've debugged Safari with Weinre, but I've found nothing.

Comment: datatype of `shipment.Date` ? Is it a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or Integer?

Comment: In order to reproduce your case please share the content of some `shipment.Date`

Comment: shipment.Date is a Date

Comment: Unless you can provide details (such as the values of *shipment.Date* and *day* and how they're generated) or an example that reproduces the error, any answer will be a guess. The outer brackets in `(date.getTime() != day.getTime())` are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, I dont know how, but the following is working :

```
shipments.forEach(shipment =>{
    var date = new Date(shipment.Date);
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    var numberDay = shipment.Date.toString().substring(8, 10)
    date.setDate(parseInt(numberDay));

    if((date.getTime() != day.getTime())){
      shipments = shipments.filter(x => x.Id != shipment.Id);
    }
  })
```

Comment: `var numberDay = shipment.Date.toString().substring(8, 10); date.setDate(parseInt(numberDay));` sets the date to its current value, it's pointless. `date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` sets the time to 00:00:00.00. The question and answer are of no use to anyone as you still haven't disclosed how the dates are set or their values. I can guess that one is set to 00:00:00 and the other isn't, but how to fix that reliably is still not answered.

Answer (score -1):

By default, calling getTime on a date object will return a number like `1543609232286`, a unix timestamp.

I'd recommend using a date/time library, such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

That would allow you to do calculations like:

```
import { isBefore, isAfter } from 'date-fns'

let before = isBefore(firstDate, secondDate)
let after = isAfter(firstDate, secondDate)
```

Comment: *getTime* returns a number, not a string, which is an ECMAScript time value. Answers that are just "use library *x*" are not answers, they might be comments.